# Git - Fatal: Will not delete all non-push URLs

Tags: git

When trying to remove the default url in my repo, I issued the command:

```
git remote set-url --delete origin https://github.com/dpressey/barberapp.git
```

I received the error as shown above in the title. How do I delete this "https" url and then add an "ssh" url, so that i can push to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reset the origin to a different url, you can directly override it:

```
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://yournewurl
```

and verify it using:

```
$ git remote -v
```

Answer (score 11):

From [Git's `remote` documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), `--delete` should work with:

`git remote set-url --push --delete origin [https://github.com/dpressey/barberapp.git]`

because the syntax is `--delete <name> <url>` where `<url>` is a regular expression.

---

As a side note, it should be pointed that there is also `git remote rm <name>` that deletes every remotes matching the given name, whatever the URLs.

Comment: Thank you for `git remote rm origin` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The usage for `delete` is as follows in the documentation -

```
usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

    --push                manipulate push URLs
    --add                 add URL
    --delete              delete URLs
```

So first, find the `name` in your local using `git remote -v`

```
backend-oss     git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/DevOps/backend/backend-oss (fetch)
backend-oss     git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/DevOps/backend/backend-oss (push)
```

As the name is `backend-oss` in my case, we will have to issue the command as below -

`git remote set-url --delete backend-oss git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/Devops/backend/backend-oss`